# Why calculate the remainders here?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to solve a question on [LeetCode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/decoded-string-at-index/):

> An encoded string S is given.  To find and write the decoded string to a tape, the encoded string is read one character at a time and the following steps are taken:
>
> - If the character read is a letter, that letter is written onto the tape.
> - If the character read is a digit (say d), the entire current tape is repeatedly written d-1 more times in total.
>
> Now for some encoded string S, and an index K, find and return the K-th letter (1 indexed) in the decoded string.

The most [upvoted solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/decoded-string-at-index/discuss/156747/C%2B%2BPython-O(N)-Time-O(1)-Space) goes like this:

```
string decodeAtIndex(string S, int K) {
    long N = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; N < K; ++i)
        N = isdigit(S[i]) ? N * (S[i] - '0') : N + 1;
    while (i--)
        if (isdigit(S[i]))
            N /= S[i] - '0', K %= N;     // what's the intuition for this
        else if (K % N-- == 0)           // and this?
            return string(1, S[i]);
    return "lee215";
}
```

While I carried out a dry-run over the code using pen-and-paper, I am not sure I fully understand the intuition behind the commented lines.

How does this work?

Comment: In the explanation, he says he's trying to "go back".  _How_?

Comment: Please don't use online judge or competition sites as a learning resource, because they're really not. They tend to promote bad habits and "clever" (but often unreadable) code that is hard to understand.

Comment: You build the length of the output covered by a prefix of the string sufficient to get to K characters, then keep looking back until you find the letter that the Kth character came from by undoing the replications.

Comment: @Some. They don't really promote anything besides learning to solve problems like this. The fact that many of the solutions tend to be badly written is a whole different can of worms. There's nothing wrong with learning to fulfill an arbitrary set of space and timing requirements. Not necessarily a good place to start learning though, I agree.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, could you please elaborate "_undoing the replications_"?

Comment: Work though a simple example like "abc23", 7. "2" creates a string of length 6, "3" makes the length 18 > 7. Now the 7th character came from somewhere in the previous 6 characters. The modulo tells you where. Now replace 7 with 11 or so and see what happens.